# Smallest phone screen to design for

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, and I was wondering the smallest screen size I should design for... I covered my bases with horizontal scrolling, but implementing horizontal *and* vertical scrolling without code breaking seems to be a pain, so I was wondering what the smallest *reasonable* screen size would be for an android phone...

Thanks!

P.S. I did see [this question,](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53911/what-is-the-smallest-screen-size-you-design-for)  but it didn't really answer my question, since it was about laptop screen sizes... Also, in android studio, the dimensions are listed like this: 480x800, etc. What do these numbers mean?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate but might be outdated as the accepted answer is from 2014: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/screen-size-to-start-designing-in-android

Comment: "480x800" will be the screen size in pixels: 480 pixel wide by 800 pixels tall. However, pixel density will change the perceived physical area - on a retina screen where the pixel density is roughly 2x a standard PC monitor (144 pixels per inch instead of 72 pixels per inch) the image may appear roughly half the size but with clearer, sharper details. You should check with your dev team to find the best way to design for output to higher pixel densities that they can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

480x800 is the size of an android device screen/view in Pixels.

For us to choose sizes we generally either:

- See what the most popular screen size is among users and go with that
- OR talk to the devs and see what size they prefer. For example our devs like 320 x 480 px as its the smallest we cater for and its easier to scale up than down. (coincidentally its one of our most popular screen sizes).